# Trailing slash

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

How can I add a trailing slash to:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|html)$ index.php
```

I have tried with:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ $1/ [R]
```

But it's not working

Comment: Looks OK to me (.+ should really be .* though)

Comment: Can you give us some more information? Maybe about how you have tested that rule.

Comment: The content I posted is what my .htacess contains, this one's RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|html)$ index.php copied from Zend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the detail/description line for the CondPatterns -d and -f for [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond). See how it says "tests whether or not it exists, and is a regular file"? That is expensive and does not scale well at all. Do you really care if it's "a regular file"? No, you only care if it *looks* like a file. *(matches the filename.extension pattern)* So, I'm going to improve your Rewrite while I'm at it.

See the detail/description for the 'last|L' flag for [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule). See how it says "don't apply any more rewrite rules"? I bet that's what you want isn't it? You want **either** index.php to be used when a request doesn't match the extension of a static asset, **OR** you want to put a slash on the end of a request that doesn't match the filename.extension pattern. Not both.

Here's how you do that:

```
# turn on matching
RewriteEngine on

# 1st rule block. If any of the conditions don't apply skip over this block to the next.
# condition: uri ends with filename.extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  [^/.]+\.[^/.]+$
# condition: uri doesn't end with a desired extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|html)$ [NC]
# rewrite the request to be for index.php and don't apply any more rules
RewriteRule -  index.php [L]

# 2nd rule block. If any of the conditions don't apply skip over this block to the next.
# condition: uri doesn't end with a slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !/$
# condition: uri doesn't end with filename.extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !/[^/]+\.[^/.]+$
# rewrite the request to be appended with a slash
RewriteRule (.*)  $1/ [R=301]
```

This is a very good answer considering that you didn't tell us want you are trying to do. If you want a better answer, you'll need to give us more info than "I copied and pasted 2 code snipets together, but it's not working."

---

**Update:** I hastily threw together an edit to this answer based on cornegigouille's answer. Here is a bash shell transcript of the proof I did to test it. Let me know if you see a bug.

```
#bruno:~$ (
for str in asdf asdf.css asdf.min.css; do
    echo -e "\n## $str ##"
    echo /brunobronosky1/$str | grep -E '/[^/.]+\.[^/.]+$' || echo '[no match]'
    echo /brunobronosky2/$str | grep -E '/[^/]+\.[^/.]+$' || echo '[no match]'
    echo /cornegigouille/$str | grep -E '/[^/.]+(\.[^/.]+)+$' || echo '[no match]'
done
)

## asdf ##
[no match]
[no match]
[no match]

## asdf.css ##
/brunobronosky1/asdf.css
/brunobronosky2/asdf.css
/cornegigouille/asdf.css

## asdf.min.css ##
[no match]
/brunobronosky2/asdf.min.css
/cornegigouille/asdf.min.css
```

Comment: NOTE: To maintain the integrity of @cornegigouille's answer, I want to record that I originally had a dot in the first character set of the last RewriteCond, like so: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !/[^/.]+\.[^/.]+$` That was an error that made my code brittle. I have since corrected it thanks to them caring enough to point it out.

Answer (score 1):

Bruno's answer is great but incomplete.
It doesn't address the case where a filename contains multiple dots. This is quite common when you start using minification (e.g. *www.mysite.com/css/styles.min.css*).

The 2nd condition of the 2nd rule block should therefore be :

```
# condition: uri doesn't end with filename.extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !/[^/.]+(\.[^/.]+)+$
```

Comment: 7 years later... nice!

Comment: Yes, 7 years later doesn't help the OP but it helps the community.

Comment: Great catch, @cornegigouille. However, I think my mistake can be corrected by lessening the complexity of the regex rather than increasing it. Does this seem to work for you? `for str in /asdfcss /asdf.css /asdf.min.css; do echo "## $str ##"; echo $str | grep -E '/[^/]+\.[^/.]+$'; done` I think it does, but I may be mentally out of context after so long.

Comment: I also think it works. And yes : simpler is better! thanks